# How to find the node with outgoing relationship but no relationship on 2nd degree nodes

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

One question, I have 15000 nodes, with relationships. suppose few of them look like this all have the same label like number but different properties. also the relationship type is the same. Now i want to see if there are any nodes where inter relationship does not exist.

```
   N
    |  
  L--F--M 
   /
H-B-G
 /
A 
 \C-D
     \E
```

like is there any query which will help me to find the nodes N,M,L related to F but no relationship with each other. start node is A. Can i check that with cipher query? i was trying with the path but it was giving me the path exist between two nodes which i define but not random n number of nodes connected to one x node.
thanks,

Comment: Can you give us more details of the domain?  Finding this example very hard to follow.  If you're starting with A and N, L, M are result nodes because they're not linked to one another, why isn't E a result node?

Comment: A is the start node, from A i want to find which nodes have connections which are not connected to each other. I used this queyr 
`START n=node(*),m=node(*) MATCH p=n-[r*0..1]-m  WITH count(p) AS totalPaths,n,m  WHERE totalPaths < 2 AND NOT ((m)-->())
RETURN n,m,totalPaths`  
`    N
      |
L--F--M `. Idea of implementation is this. I am calling to my friend and my friend is working in an office and calls to customer numbers. These customers have no relationship with each other. i want to see my friend F calling to customers which have no relationships with eachother.